# Xor and Sum of n numbers, n >2

Tags: sum, xor

Is it possible to have n numbers whose sum and xor are equal?

When I asked this question to Chat GPT it says it is not possible..

For n = 2,

we can have so many pairs,
1 and 6, 2 and 3 so on...

Is it possible for n = 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are plenty solutions, also for `n=3` and `n=4`

```
const int dim = 100;

for (int i1 = 1; i1< dim; i1++)
   for (int i2 = i1; i2 < dim; i2++)
       for (int i3 = i2; i3 < dim; i3++)
           for (int i4 = i3; i4 < dim; i4++)
               if ((i1+i2+i3+i4) == (i1 ^ i2 ^ i3 ^ i4))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine($"{i1} {i2} {i3} {i4}");
               }
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 8
1 2 4 16
1 2 4 24
1 2 4 32
1 2 4 40
1 2 4 48
1 2 4 56
1 2 4 64
1 2 4 72
1 2 4 80
1 2 4 88
1 2 4 96
1 2 8 16
1 2 8 20
1 2 8 32
1 2 8 36
1 2 8 48
1 2 8 52
1 2 8 64
1 2 8 68
1 2 8 80
1 2 8 84
1 2 8 96
....
```